# Remove Bounds icon on google maps marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

currently I created pages with google maps api v3, and there is a marker that user can drag. after dragend, the script with draw blue line on the road between marker. my problem is shown 2 marker on destination (a marker and "B" marker)

I've try using fitbounds() but still facing my problem.

```
<div id="current"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.760722, 110.408761),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.760722, 110.408761), 
    map: map,
    draggable:true
});
google.maps.event.addListener(
    marker,
    'dragend',
    function() {
        console.log(marker.position.lat());
        console.log(marker.position.lng());
        var msv = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.760722, 110.408761);
        var mgw = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng());




        var request = {
            origin: msv,
            destination: mgw,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
            {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Directions Request from " + start.toUrlValue(6) + " to " + end.toUrlValue(6) + " failed: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

how to remove bound marker ("B" marker) on destination? I expect there is only one marker in destination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all the markers (with the `{suppressMarkers:true}` option on the `DirectionsRenderer` (they can't be suppressed separately)

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  suppressMarkers: true
});
```

To make the "A" Marker appear, create it:

```
var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: msv,
  label: {
    text: "A",
    color: "white"
  }
})
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8u4r7xkt/6/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  suppressMarkers: true
});
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 14,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.760722, 110.408761),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.760722, 110.408761),
  map: map,
  draggable: true
});
google.maps.event.addListener(
  marker,
  'dragend',
  function() {
    console.log(marker.position.lat());
    console.log(marker.position.lng());
    var msv = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.760722, 110.408761);
    var mgw = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng());
    // add "A" marker
    var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: msv,
      label: {
        text: "A",
        color: "white"
      }
    })

    var request = {
      origin: msv,
      destination: mgw,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      } else {
        alert("Directions Request from " + start.toUrlValue(6) + " to " + end.toUrlValue(6) + " failed: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="current"></div>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```